# How to remove these blank margins with IE 9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Can you tell me how to remove these blank margins with Internet Explorer 9?

[image]

Note that it works perfectly with Chrome.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="left" style="width:18px;float:left;display:inline-block;">
        <img src="left.png" width="18" height="37" />
    </div>
    <div id="right" style="width:400px;float:right;">
        <img src="right.png" width="400" height="37" />
    </div>
    <div id="center" style="margin: 0 400px 0 18px;" class="middleBar">
        <div id="info">
            <marquee>A message</marquee>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Among the 3 `div`, the middle one (with `id="center"`) is extensible.

Here's my CSS:

```
.middleBar{
    background-image: url(../images/yyy.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='zzz.png',
        sizingMethod='scale' );
    _background-image: none;
    height: 37px;
}
```

Is this problem is the *Three Pixel Jog*?

Comment: You should note that `<marquee>` is no longer a valid element under HTML5 and was deprecated.

Comment: I know this but it's not the point.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? The order of your div structure doesn't make sense (left, center, right would be easier).

Comment: The order of my `div` structure does make sense because the one in the middle is extensible in relation to the width of the screen.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the problem?